# Alternatives to cglib for implementing Android lazy loading

Tags: java, android, lazy-loading, dalvik, cglib

I'm currently working on a framework for Android which includes an ORM. I'm planning on incorporating lazy loading into the ORM, which, outside of Android, can be achieved using the cglib bytecode-manipulation framework. However, since cglib is incompatible with Dalvik, I obviously cannot utilize it for this purpose.

What Android-compatible alternatives are there which can help me to implement lazy loading?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at [dexmaker](http://code.google.com/p/dexmaker/)

Comment: Thanks, I was able to implement lazy loading using dexmaker, although `ProxyBuilder`'s `build` method seems to take an extraordinarily long time to generate `Proxy` instances.